# android application uninstall protection

Tags: android, uninstallation

Just wanted to know is there a way to protect an application from getting uninstalled. I know it's possible if i add the application as a device administrator but this is not enough.

Is there a way I could pop up a message asking for the security code before un-installation starts ? any ideas highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two applications. The first will be you application and the second will listen for remove intents and will triger an action if your first applications is removed, but this is only a basic protection since the user can remove the second application first.

Comment: You could do that, but you are still unable to prevent uninstallation - the second app would only know that the first was removed but would be unable to prevent it in any way. I suppose you could then attempt to reinstall the first app, but you would have trouble doing it non-interactively on a non-rooted device, and you would also risk losing any local data used by the first app unless it takes special measures to store it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible solution is to modify the android source. As there are applications that can't be removed (gmail, contacts, telefon app, sms app, facebook, twitter) there must be a flag that you can use for your requirement. But I doubt that there is a way on a non customized android os...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible If application is installed by user.
Application can be uninstall by user too.

Answer (score 0):

I think "application protection" on the market do what you want.
Try to implement an BroadCastReceiver listen ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.